# Declare date using awk

Tags: shell, unix, sunos

I need help in completing the below script in shell.
Requested format is to print previous, current and next business days (should exclude weekends and holidays).
text name : holiday.txt

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
cur_date=`date +"%A %m/%d/%Y"`                                  
cur_day=`date +"%A"`                                                            
yesterday=`TZ=AEDT+13 date +"%A %m/%d/%Y"`;       
twodd_back=`TZ=AEDT+37 date +"%A %m/%d/%Y"`;  
tomorrow=`TZ=AEDT-35 date +"%A %m/%d/%Y"`;     
twodd_later=`TZ=AEDT-59 date +"%A %m/%d/%Y"`;    
cdate=`date +"%m/%d/%Y"`
####################
echo "Previous Business Day is $yesterday"
    if echo $yesterday|awk '{print $1}'=Saturday 
         then echo "Previous Business Day is $twodd_back"    
    fi  
echo "Current Business Day is $ cur_date"
echo " Next Business Day is $tomorrow"
```

Comment: Is this not working? What about it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

The script in its current status does not execute successfully. It fails with below error.

```
awk: syntax error at source line 1
context is
{print >>>  $1}= <<< Saturday
awk: bailing out at source line 1
```

To fix it, change your if statement.

```
if [[ `echo $yesterday | awk '{print $1}'` = Saturday ]];
```